# How to use DenseArray in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I have tried to initialize DenseArray using

```
   julia> a = DenseArray{Int64,10}
DenseArray{Int64, 10}

julia> a
DenseArray{Int64, 10}
#access first element
julia> a[1]
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type DenseArray{Int64, 10}
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, ::LinearAlgebra.Factorization) where T<:AbstractArray at C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr
\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\LinearAlgebra\src\factorization.jl:58
  convert(::Type{T}, ::T) where T<:AbstractArray at abstractarray.jl:14
  convert(::Type{T}, ::T) where T at essentials.jl:205
Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(A::Vector{DenseArray{Int64, 10}}, x::Int64, i1::Int64)
   @ Base .\array.jl:843
 [2] getindex(#unused#::Type{DenseArray{Int64, 10}}, x::Int64)
   @ Base .\array.jl:392
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[3]:1

julia>
```

Can anybody give an example to initialize a dense array with some values and a way to access array elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`DenseArray` is an abstract datatype, as documented [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Implementation), you cannot construct a `DenseArray`.**

Incidentally, in your code `a` is a `DataType`:

```
julia> a = DenseArray{Int64, 10}
DenseArray{Int64, 10}

julia> typeof(a)
DataType
```

If you would try to actually contruct a `DenseArray`, the error message you get makes sense, knowing that `DenseArray` is an abstract type:

```
julia> a = DenseArray{Int64, 2}(undef, 3, 3)
ERROR: MethodError: no constructors have been defined for DenseMatrix{Int64}
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[99]:1
```

The message tells you there are no constructors, which is why you cannot construct one. If you want the functionality of a `DenseArray`, you should therefore use one of its concrete subtypes. You can check for subtypes in the REPL:

```
julia> subtypes(DenseArray)
9-element Vector{Any}:
 Array
 Base.CodeUnits
 Base.Experimental.Const
 FFTW.FakeArray
 GPUArraysCore.AbstractGPUArray
 LabelledArrays.LArray
 Random.UnsafeView
 SharedArrays.SharedArray
 SparseArrays.CHOLMOD.Dense
```

You can see `Array` in the list, and I would guess this is the one you want for most use-cases. Any `Array` you construct will be a `DenseArray`, you can make one like this:

```
julia> a = Array{Int64, 2}(undef, 3, 3)
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
```

And you can see that `a` really is a `DenseArray`:

```
julia> a isa DenseArray
true
```